# Array List Item Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Is there a way of doing this:

```
var numbers = [156,845,34,849,5,48,54,8,879];
```

and then a condition to check the array to see if there are any values that are less than 10 and for it to output the index value of each item that is less than 10?

So the above would output 4 & 7

**THANK YOU EVERYONE THIS IS NOW WORKING**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = [];
for(key in numbers) {
    if (numbers[key] < 10) results.push(key);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [156,845,34,849,5,48,54,8,879];

var indexes=[];

numbers.map(function(num,index){ 
    if(num < 10) indexes.push(index);
})
console.log(indexes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not write a function to do this?

```
function membersLessThan(array, value)
{
    var indices = [];

    for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < value) indices.push(i);
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Edit:  Usage example:

```
var numbers = [156,845,34,849,5,48,54,8,879];

// contains 4 and 7
var lessthanten = membersLessThan(numbers, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work:

```
var numbers = [156, 845, 34, 849, 5, 48, 54, 8, 879];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] < 10) {
        console.log(numbers.indexOf(numbers[i]));
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trmuevog/)

Answer (score 1):

Can use `.each()`. Example:

```js
    var numbers = [156,845,34,849,5,48,54,8,879];
    var ind_arr = [];
    $.each(numbers, function(ind, val){
        if(val < 10){
            ind_arr.push(ind);
        }
    });
    alert(ind_arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```